# python requests-html Chromium process leaking

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, chromium, python-requests-html

My program cannot run thought the entire loop because a leak crashes it before it gets to the end.

I have the following script:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for x in range(9376,23534):
    session = HTMLSession()

    r = session.get('https://someexampleurl.com/yadayada/database1/{}'.format(x))

    r.html.render()  # this call executes the js in the page

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.html.html, features="lxml")
    
    r.close()
    print(x)

    name = "\n".join([img['alt'] for img in soup.find_all('img', alt=True)])
    name = name[1:]
    name = name[:-1]

    url = "\n".join([img['src'] for img in soup.find_all('img', alt=True)])
    
    def solve_fast(s):
        ind1 = s.find('\n')
        ind2 = s.rfind('\n')
        return s[ind1+1:ind2]
    
    url = solve_fast(url)
    
    url = url[0:41] + "1" + url[41+1: ]
    url = url[0:42] + "2" + url[42+1: ]
    url = url[0:43] + "8" + url[43+1: ]

    img_data = requests.get(url)

    with open('local_database1/{}{}.avif'.format(x,name), 'wb') as handler:
                handler.write(img_data.content)

    img_data.close()
```

When ran in a loop the chromium process stacks up infinitely until the program crashes, I can't see where I am not closing the connection to the request.

Comment: since when requests uses Chromium? These two things are unrelated

Comment: Maybe `soup.decompose()` when you're done with `soup`. Move the `def` out of the loop, there's no need to redefine that every iteration. Possibly use `str(img['alt'])` and `str(img['src'])` instead of just `img['alt']` and `img['src']` to disassociate from the `bs4` objects.

Comment: @Marat ```r.html.render()  "# this call executes the js in the page``` this line creates the chromium. "(from the docs) Note, the first time you ever run the render() method, it will download Chromium into your home directory (e.g. ~/.pyppeteer/)." and as you can see I am calling r.close()

Comment: @RvBVakama I overlooked the the first import. The question is about `requests-html` - which, indeed, uses Chromium,  while the vanilla `requests` doesn't. I fixed the tags

Answer (score 0):

In my case **session.close()**  works for me.

Code

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://xxxxxxxx')
r.html.render()

...

session.close()
```